# Procesar form múltiple en un solo archivo Php

Tags: php, formularios, submit

Tengo el siguiente código:

```
    <div class="modal" id="modal">
        <div class="centlimitesubs">
            <form action=""  onsubmit="return false" name="conlimi" 
               class="general" method="POST">

                    <label class="titulo3">Emisión AS/400</label><br>
                    <input required type="number" onkeyup="format(this)" onchange="format(this)" align="center" class="inpt" name="as" min='0'><br><br>

                    <label class="titulo3">Emisión Web</label><br>
                    <input required type="number" onkeyup="format(this)" onchange="format(this)" align="center" class="inpt" name="web" min='0'><br><br>

                    <label class="titulo3">Renovación</label><br>
                    <input required type="number" onkeyup="format(this)" onchange="format(this)" align="center" class="inpt" name="renova" min='0'><br><br>

                    <label class="titulo3">Incremento En Lote</label><br>
                    <input required type="number" onkeyup="format(this)" onchange="format(this)" align="center" class="inpt" name="lote" min='0'><br><br>

                    <label class="titulo3">Fecha Desde:</label><br>
                    <input class="inpt" align="center" required type="date" name="fecha" min="<?php echo date("Y-m-d",strtotime($fecant."+ 1 days")); ?>">

                </div>
                <div class="bot">
                    <input type="submit" name="general-submit" value="Actualizar" class="boton botoniz">
                    <button type="button" class="boton botonde botondem" id="botoncerrar">Cancelar</button>

                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>

   <div class="modal2" id="modal2">
       <div class="centlimitesubs2">
           <form action="" id="form2" class="lote" onsubmit="return false" name="conlimi2" method="POST">

                    <input type="hidden" value="formB" name="parametro"/>           

                    <label class="titulo3">Incremento En Lote</label><br>
                    <input required type="number" align="center" class="inpt" name="loteaum" min='0'><br><br>

                   <label class="titulo3">Fecha Desde:</label><br>
                   <input class="inpt" align="center" required type="date" name="fechas" min="<?php echo date("Y-m-d",strtotime($fecant."+ 1 days")); ?>">
               </div>

               <div class="bot">
                   <input type="submit" value="Actualizarlote" name="lote-submit" class="boton botoniz">
                   <button type="button" class="boton botonde botondem" id="botoncerrar2">Cancelar</button>
               </div>

           </form>
       </div>
   </div>
```

y mi controller.php tengo lo siguente:

```
if(isset( $_POST['general-submit'] ))  {

//Aca proceso los datos del primer Submit

}

else if(isset( $_POST['lote-submit'] ))  {

//y aca del segundo
}
```

Pero nunca entra en el segundo form, es decir, no he podido procesar el segundo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En tu segundo formulario hay un error, pues hay un `div` que se cierra sin previa apertura, por lo que puede que el HTML no esté validando.

Intenta a corregirlo de este modo:

```
   <div class="modal2" id="modal2">
       <div class="centlimitesubs2">
           <form action="" id="form2" class="lote" onsubmit="return false" name="conlimi2" method="POST">
               <!-- Aquí falta abrir un div -->
               <div>
                    <input type="hidden" value="formB" name="parametro"/>           
                    <label class="titulo3">Incremento En Lote</label><br>
                    <input required type="number" align="center" class="inpt" name="loteaum" min='0'><br><br>

                   <label class="titulo3">Fecha Desde:</label><br>
                   <input class="inpt" align="center" required type="date" name="fechas" min="<?php echo date('Y-m-d',strtotime($fecant.'+ 1 days')); ?>" />
               </div>

               <div class="bot">
                   <input type="submit" value="Actualizarlote" name="lote-submit" class="boton botoniz">
                   <button type="button" class="boton botonde botondem" id="botoncerrar2">Cancelar</button>
               </div>

           </form>
       </div>
   </div>
```